# Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста сделать закрытие спойлера при нажатии мышки на область

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sp').on('click', '.extremum-click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.extremum-slide').slideToggle(0);

  });
});
```

```css
.extremum-slide {
  display: none;
}

.postboxx {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 18px 20px 0px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}

.postfled {
  height: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}

.boxbotton {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top: 0px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}

.vkizi {
  border: 0px solid #e3e4e8;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sp">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="postboxx extremum-click">
      <div class="postfled">
        <style>
           :active,
           :hover,
           :focus {
            outline: 0;
            outline-offset: 0;
          }
        </style>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Роман">
        <div style="margin-left: 43px;">
          <textarea class="vkizi" cols="60" name="message" rows="" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extremum-slide">
      <div class="boxbotton">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="1523707704_68.jpg">
        <div style="height: 33px;">
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: что мешает при клике добавить скрывающий css-класс?

Comment: Как бы костыля не было. http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Скрыть_элемент_при_клике_за_его_пределами

Comment: Не понятно, на какую область?

Comment: Скрыть элемент при клике за его пределами.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {

  // указываем класс который не будет скрывать форму при клике в нутри формы
  if ($(event.target).closest(".snow").length)
    return;

  //указываем класс который будет скрыт при клике за пределами формы
  $("#skryt").fadeOut("slow");
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```

```css
.postbox {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 18px 20px 0px 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}

.boxbotton {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-top: 0px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-left: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
}

.vkizisex {
  border: 0px solid #e3e4e8;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: left;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <div id="pokazat"></div>
  <div class="snow">
    <div class="postbox" onClick="document.getElementById('pokazat').style.display='none';document.getElementById('skryt').style.display='';return  false;">
      <div class="postfled">
        <style>
           :active,
           :hover,
           :focus {
            outline: 0;
            outline-offset: 0;
          }
        </style>

        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Роман">
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left;line-height: 1.10em;color: #060;"></i>
        <div style="margin-left: 43px;">
          <textarea class="vkizisex" cols="60" name="message" rows="" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Что у Вас нового?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="skryt" style="display:none">
      <div class="boxbotton">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="1523707704_68.jpg">
        <div style="height: 33px;">
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" class="vksex">
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```